# Activity regularizer in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

In Keras, for dense layers, we can use the parameter activity_regularizer.
In Tensorflow, there is no similar parameter.

Keras :

```
from keras import regularizers
encoding_dim = 32
input_img = Input(shape=(784,))
# add a Dense layer with a L1 activity regularizer
encoded = Dense(encoding_dim, activation='relu', activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(10e-5))(input_img)
decoded = Dense(784, activation='sigmoid')(encoded)
autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
```

How to make an activity_regularizer in tensorflow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Keras documentation is not too precise, but from what I've read the activity regularization is simply a L1 or L2 term for the output of a specific layer added to the corresponding loss function of the model.

So let's say you have some loss, for example the MSE for some labels:

```
loss = tf.metrics.mean_squared_error(labels, model_output)
```

To add L1 activity regularization to a certain layer you would simply add the L1 regularization term for the output of that layer to your loss with some regularization strength (I'll take `10e-5` like given in your question):

```
loss += 10e-5*tf.nn.l1_loss(layer_output)
```

Where `layer_output` is the output of the layer you want to regulate.

If you did the same with the layer's weights instead of its output you would have what the Keras [documentation](https://keras.io/regularizers/) calls kernel regularization. If you do the same for the bias vector of that layer you get Keras's bias regularization.

Answer (score 3):

- tensorflow implements the Keras API in `tf.keras`, so technically if it is defined in Keras it is/should be in tensorflow.
- other high-level APIs in tensorflow have a similar behavior. For example `tf.layer.Dense` has `kernel_regularizer` and `bias_regularizer` arguments in its constructor.
- If you do not want to use high-level APIs but rather implement everything yourself, you can add a regularizer to your loss. An L2 regularizer on a parameter for example is achieved by adding the sum of its squared elements to your loss multiplied by some constant related to the strength to this constraint. (The `10e-5` factor in your example).